# compilation error while installing R package 'maftools' on M1 mac

Tags: r, compilation, apple-m1

I'm trying to install R package 'maftools' on my mac M1.

As other M1 mac users, I encountered compilation issue while installing dependent packages like 'DNAcopy' or 'Rhtslib'. I solved this by directly installing 'xz' within /opt/R/arm64/ (ref -https://github.com/Bioconductor/Rhtslib/issues/23#issuecomment-848448454)

Although above two packages were succesfully installed without any issue after haveing 'lzma' & 'lzma.h' in /opt/R/arm64/include/,  installing 'maftools' still says 'compilation error'

`BiocManager::install("maftools", type="source")`

```
* installing *source* package ‘maftools’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG     File /Users/cswc/.Renviron contains invalid line(s)       GITHUB_PAT    They were ignored  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rhtslib/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/zlibbioc/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ntcounts.c -o ntcounts.o
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG     File /Users/cswc/.Renviron contains invalid line(s)       GITHUB_PAT    They were ignored  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/Rhtslib/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/zlibbioc/include' -I/opt/R/arm64/include   -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c ntcounts.c -o ntcounts.o'
make: *** [ntcounts.o] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘maftools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/maftools’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/p8/f28qvb_j7p70b67bzygm666m0000gn/T/RtmpI9NPdm/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘maftools’ had non-zero exit status
```

I checked the status of xcode-select and gfortran,

```
/usr/bin/xcode-select #for xcode
/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran #for gfortran
```

I don't know which part is wrong with compilation error.
Does any one have a similar issue with me ?

Here's my sessionInfo();

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.4         utf8_1.2.3          dplyr_1.1.3         grid_4.2.0          R6_2.5.1            gtable_0.3.4        lifecycle_1.0.3     magrittr_2.0.3     
 [9] scales_1.2.1        ggplot2_3.4.3       pillar_1.9.0        rlang_1.1.1         cli_3.6.1           data.table_1.14.8   rstudioapi_0.15.0   vctrs_0.6.3        
[17] generics_0.1.3      cowplot_1.1.1       tools_4.2.0         glue_1.6.2          munsell_0.5.0       compiler_4.2.0      colorspace_2.1-0    pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[25] BiocManager_1.30.22 tidyselect_1.2.0    tibble_3.2.1
```

Comment: If the complaint about `.Renviron` is really part of the command line, then that is likely the problem.  Have you tried removing offending things from your `.Renviron` file?

Comment: Hi ! Yes, you're right. It was because of accidentally added wrong line in '.Renvion' file. After deleting that line solved the issue. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

My practice in macOS is that if a first attempt to compile from source does not succeed then install from binary, as I just did on my M1 successfully with

```
BiocManager::install("maftools")
```

Ordinary users (we who do not spend a substantial amount of time in development of compiled languages) have better things to do with our time than chase down compiler toolchain issues.